# IOS Core Data, UITableView load more data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

in my IOS project i using Core Data. I have 1000 elements
First of all, I need to show in UITableView 30 elements. When the user scrolls and reaches the bottom of an UITableView (5 elements to the end) so I can load new data into the table.
How can i do that

I used this code but it does not work the way I wanted

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "GDMnLineRKObjectManager.h"
#import "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h"
#import "CinNames.h"
#import "Event.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property NSUInteger dpc;
@property BOOL is_load;
@property BOOL process_loading;
@property NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL loadingMoreTableViewData;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger  inf_counter;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController
//@synthesize tableView;

- (IBAction)showMenu
{
    // Dismiss keyboard (optional)
    //
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.frostedViewController.view endEditing:YES];

    // Present the view controller
    //
    [self.frostedViewController presentMenuViewController];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


- (void)saveToStore
{
    // Saving to persistent store for further usage.
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.dpc = 0;
    self.inf_counter = self.dpc;
    self.is_load = NO;
    self.process_loading = NO;

    self.fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Event class])];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    /*

     */
    [self loadElements];
    ////
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    ///
}


- (void)loadElements
{

    // Get an array of remote "character" objects. Specify the offset.
    [[GDMnLineRKObjectManager manager] getMnLineObjectsAtPath:SERVER_PATH_LOAD
                                                   parameters:@{@"someval" : @("564")}
                                                      success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

                                                      }
                                                      failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                          // Failed to load characters.
                                                          /*
                                                           [self animateActivityIndicator:NO];
                                                           [bottomPullView finishedLoading];
                                                           */
                                                          [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Marvel API Error" message:operation.error.localizedDescription delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Retry", nil] show];
                                                      }];
}



#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"III = %@", indexPath);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HuCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

     if (indexPath.row > self.inf_counter - 5) {
     // User has scrolled to the bottom of the list of available data so simulate loading some more if we aren't already
         if (!self.loadingMoreTableViewData && self.process_loading == NO) {
             self.loadingMoreTableViewData = YES;
             self.process_loading = YES;
             [self performSelector:@selector(addSomeMoreEntriesToTableView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
         }
     }
     if (indexPath.row < self.inf_counter) {
         [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
     } else {
         cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading more data...";
     }
    return cell;
}



- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString * string3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %ld", [[object valueForKey:@"name"] description], (long)indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =  string3;//[[object valueForKey:@"name"] description];
}


#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    NSLog(@"Skolko");
    if ((!_fetchedResultsController || self.process_loading == YES))  {

        self.process_loading = NO;
        self.is_load = NO;
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
        self.fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
        self.fetchRequest.fetchLimit = self.dpc;
        //self.fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 30;

        self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
        self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

        NSError *error;

        [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

        NSLog(@"%@",[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]);

        NSLog(@"Counta: %lu",(unsigned long)[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]);

        NSAssert(!error, @"Error performing fetch request: %@", error);
        self.inf_counter = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)addSomeMoreEntriesToTableView {
    self.dpc += 20;
    [self fetchedResultsController];
    self.loadingMoreTableViewData = NO;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scroll {

     // UITableView only moves in one direction, y axis
     CGFloat currentOffset = scroll.contentOffset.y;
     CGFloat maximumOffset = scroll.contentSize.height - scroll.frame.size.height;
     NSLog(@"hui = %f", (maximumOffset - currentOffset));
     // Change 10.0 to adjust the distance from bottom
     if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 10.0) {
         self.is_load = YES;
         self.dpc += 10;
         [self fetchedResultsController];
         //[self.tableView reloadData];
     }


}
@end
```

Comment: What have you thought about? Have you looked at the classes apple provides and seen anything useful?

Comment: Yes, i looked Apple classes and I could not find anything

Comment: [self.tableView beginUpdates]
//calls to insert/move and delete methods   
//operations on our data source so that its
//state is consistent with state of the table view
[self.tableView endUpdates]

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [fetchBatchSize](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/setFetchBatchSize:) property on `NSFetchRequest`. I hope you are also using an `NSFetchedResultsController`, it goes fantastically well with Table Views and Collection Views. Here's the description:

> You use a fetched results controller to efficiently manage the results
>   returned from a Core Data fetch request to provide data for a
>   UITableView object.

So before you setup your fetched results controller just ensure you set the fetchBatchSize of the fetch request and let the framework handle all the optimizations for you.

**EDIT**

The OP wanted the original fetch to only include 30 items and then only if the user scrolled it should repopulate the fetch. In most cases fetchBatchSize should be the solution as Core Data will seek to fault all the results and thus avoid the overhead of fetching all the objects, preferring to lazily fault them instead. To stick with the OP, the solution might be like this:

```
- (NSFetchRequest *)createFetchRequest {
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([MyEntity class])];
    fetch.predicate = //set up your fetch
    return fetch;
}
```

And then when you instantiate your controller you can set the fetch limit:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self createFetchRequest];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 30;
NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                             managedObjectContext:context
                                                                               sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
self.controller = controller;
```

since the `fetchRequest` property on the controller is readOnly you are forced to re-assign your controller when you want to fetch everything:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self createFetchRequest];
NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                                 managedObjectContext:context
                                                                                   sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
[controller performFetch:nil];
self.controller = controller;
```

If you want even more to go on, head on over to [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller), they provide awesome tutorials for everything iOS.

Happy Coding

Comment: If i used fetchBatchSize in UITableview showing (for example) 100 elements, but loaded  fetchBatchSize value (30). But first I need to show only 30 items

Comment: You could try setting the fetchLimit to 30 and then later updating your fetchRequest, i will update my solution

Comment: I showed my code and i did how you say, but my code don't work correctly

Comment: Thats because you need to reinitialize your controller. I don't fully understand why you would want to do something like this, it feels very hacky. You are also maintaining a lot of state BOOLs in your controller which is bad practice and could easily lead to bugs

Comment: Setting the batch size is wiser than setting the fetch limit. Why lie to the user about how many items there are and force the scrolling to stop and restart when you don't need to?

Comment: @Wain I concur, but like I said I'm not entirely sure why the OP wants this odd behavior but it could be for a game or anything really. This is why i detailed that in most cases fetchBatchSize should be the solution:)

Answer (score 0):

Options:

Watch the session Advanced ScrollView Techniques from WWDC 2011.

Tutorial: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html

Comment: Thanks for example, but i need a vertical scroll with uitableview and Core Data

Comment: How about applying some of the techniques in that session to your problem. Don't expect SO users to write your code for you.

Comment: I looked at this decision and unfortunately it does not solve my problem